# Reffering 2 different custom post types each other by using multi checkboxes [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a website for an artist with Wordpress. In the website, I created 2 custom post types: Works and Exhibitions, to refer each other in each post, so that viewers can understand in which exhibitions an artwork is presented on the artwork post and which artworks are presented in an exhibition on the exhibition post.

I tried using ACF's Post Object to call the list of the custom post types in admin panel. But there was no feature on Post Object with checkboxes.

The image below explains what I want to achieve.
[image]

What I think the best is to query multi checkbox values on admin post page(Add New Works). Then the artist can choose the exhibitions in which the work is presented and vise versa in an exhibition post. But I couldn't figure out how.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?
Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: What about https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Comment: Thank you, meck373! It solved. Now I regret my careless disposition.